# Searching database with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to **search** for data in my `datagrid` using the code sample below. I have had it working with the code looking a bit different, but I am now going to use **async** in my coding and I have tried to do so with the sample below, but have no idea how to change the code to work correctly.

```
    private async Task btnSearchSysproStock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (DataEntities DE = new DataEntities())
        {
            List<SSData> stockSearch = await (from a in DE.tblSysproStocks where 
                (a => txtSearchSysproStock.Text == string.Empty || a.StockCode.Contains(txtSearchSysproStock.Text)) //The error is in this line
                select new SSData
                {
                    SID = a.StockID,
                    SCode = a.StockCode,
                    SDescription = a.StockDescription,
                    SConvFactAltUom = (float)a.ConvFactAltUom,
                    ...
                }).ToListAsync();
            dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = stockSearch;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> ***Cannot convert lamba expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type***

Can anyone please help me to get this code that I am using to work. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you are using lambda in non-lambda linq expression? try something:  from a in DE.tblSysproStocks where txtSearchSysproStock.Text == string.Empty || a.StockCode.Contains(txtSearchSysproStock.Text) select ...   but your where clause is strange check what you want first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ `where` clause expects `bool` expression, you don't need lambda here :

```
from a in ...
where txtSearchSysproStock.Text == string.Empty || 
      a.StockCode.Contains(txtSearchSysproStock.Text)
select ...
```